# MySQL: #1217 when dropping tables

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've created a simple database relation consisting of the entities entry and keywords.
Any entry can have n keywords, but each keyword may only exist once in the keywords table.
To realize this, I've created three tables: entries, keywords and entries2keywords. I'd like to maintain semantic integrity, so a DELETE or UPDATE procedure should propagate to the related tables.
Another requirement for the database setup is to be re-entrant, meaning that I can just re-run the creation script in which case all data should simply be deleted, as in DROP TABLE.

However, my current script fails with a #1217 error when re-running it:

```
#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

[I've linked to the database script here](http://pastebin.com/mAmR4CX4) because it's too large to paste.

Comment: Have you tried to re-arrange the drop process? Try to drop them in this order entities>keywords>entries2keywords. See if it would solve the problem. Or it might be entries2keywords first, first table with constraints, then others.

Comment: Indeed, when dropping entries2keywords first it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, than, dropping entries2keywords (table with constraints) will solve the issue :)